# How to capture large STDOUT output in Perl when executing an external command

Tags: perl, shell, sftp

I want to get the list of file names present in the remote location.

I am using the below snippet in my Perl script.

```
my $command = "sftp -q -o${transferAuthMode}=yes -oPort=$sftpPort ${remoteUsername}\@${remoteHost} 2>\&1 <<EOF\n" . 
       "cd \"${remotePath}\"\n" . 
       "ls -l \n" . 
       "quit\n" . 
       "EOF\n";

my @files = `$command`;
```

When the number of files in the remote location is large (>500) then not all the file names are captured in `@files`.

When I manually do SFTP and list the files, all files are getting listed but I'm not getting the same through the script. Each time getting `@files` size different. It's occurring only when there are large number of files.

I'm unable find the reason behind this. Could you please help?

Comment: How many files? `perl -wE '@ar = qx{for ((i=1;i<=10000000;i++)) ; do echo \$i ; done}; say scalar @ar'` returns 10000000 correctly for me.

Comment: Maybe time to switch to [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://p3rl.org/Net::SFTP::Foreign)?

Comment: That number is not "_huge_" (for this purpose).  I'd guess that it's about the interface between sftp/shell/Perl.  I would also recommend to switch to a good module, instead of going through the system.

Comment: I suggest that you use [`Net::SFTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP) instead of shellling out to the command line utility.

Comment: Tried with  Net::SFTP::Foreign PERL module, working fine and listing all the files. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved without requiring any additional package module/s. I tested this on my CentOS 7 Server (Windows VM).

**My remote host details:** I got ~2000 files in the remote host dir. A CentOS 6.8 server.

```
%_gaurav@[remotehost]:/home/gaurav/files/test> ls -lrth|head -3;echo;ls -lrth|tail -2
total 7.9M
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 35 Feb 16 23:51 File-0.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 35 Feb 16 23:51 File-1.txt

-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 38 Feb 16 23:51 File-1998.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 gaurav gaurav 38 Feb 16 23:51 File-1999.txt
%_gaurav@[remotehost]: /home/gaurav/files/test>
```

**Script output from LocalHost:** Please note that I am running your command sans the `o${transferAuthMode}=yes` part. As seen below, the script is able to gather all results in an array, greater than 500 results.

I am prnting the total entries, some particular index numbers from the array to show the results, but give it a try with un-commented Dumper line to see the full result.

```
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/study/pl> ./scp.pl
Read 2003 lines from SCP command.

ArrayIndex: 2,3,1999,2000 contain:

[-rw-rw-r--    0 501      501           36B Feb 16 23:51 File-58.txt]
[-rw-rw-r--    0 501      501           37B Feb 16 23:51 File-129.txt]
[-rw-rw-r--    0 501      501           38B Feb 16 23:51 File-1759.txt]
[-rw-rw-r--    0 501      501           38B Feb 16 23:51 File-1810.txt]
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/study/pl>
```

**Script and its Working:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper ;

my $sftp_port=22 ;
my ($user, $host) = ("gaurav","192.168.246.137") ;
my $remote_path = '/home/gaurav/files/test' ;

my @result ;    # To store result

my $command = "sftp -q -oPort=$sftp_port ${user}\@${host} 2>\&1 <<EOF\n"."cd $remote_path\nls -lrth\nquit\nEOF" ;

# open the command as a file handle, read output and store it.
open FH, "$command |" or die "Something went wrong!!\n" ;
while (<FH>) {
  tr/(?\r|\f|\n)//d ; # Removing any new line, carriage return or form feed.
  push(@result,"\[$_\]") ;
}
close FH ;

#print Dumper @result ;

# Just for printing a little bit of results from
# the array. Following lines can be deleted.
my $total = scalar @result ;
print "Read $total lines from SCP command.\n" ;
print "\nArrayIndex: 2,3,1999,2000 contain:\n
$result[2]
$result[3]
$result[1999]
$result[2000]
" ;
```

**Another way:** One could also get around this issue by making a shell script and calling it from the perl script and read its output. As shown below, my shell script which gets called by the perl script and the final output. This can be used as a quick technique when one doesn't have much time to write/formulate commands in perl directly. *You can use the qx style(shown below) in earlier script as well*.

Shell script "scp.sh"

```
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/study/pl> cat scp.sh
#!/bin/bash

sftp -oPort=${1} ${2}@${3} 2>&1 <<EOF
cd ${4}
ls -l
quit
EOF
```

Perl Script "2scp.pl"

```
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/study/pl> cat 2scp.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Data::Dumper ;

my $sftp_port=22 ;
my ($user, $host) = ("gaurav","192.168.246.137") ;
my $remote_path = '/home/gaurav/files/test' ;

# Passing arguements to shell script using concatination.
my $command = './scp.sh '." $sftp_port $user $host $remote_path" ;

my @result = qx{$command} ;     # Runs the command and stores the result.
my $total = scalar @result ;
print "Read $total lines from SCP command.\n" ;
# End.
```

Output:

```
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/study/pl> ./2scp.pl
Read 2004 lines from SCP command.
%_STATION@gaurav * /root/ga/study/pl>
```

Try it out and let us know. 
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tried the first approach (using file handler), its worked fine and listed all the files. But slightly slow when compared to the implementation using Net::SFTP::Foreign PERL module.

Comment: Yes it would be slow as its making system calls, which is slower. But remember that this is without the perl modules and just system commands - which maybe someone's requirement or situation where they are unablet o install an additional module.